ScrollView/FlatList Conflicts with Stack.Screen in React Navigation
I'm developing a Chat screen in React Native, but I'm facing a problem when using Stack.Screen together with elements like Flatlist or ScrollView.
My code is as follows:
import { Stack, useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { FlatList, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { dataChats, images } from '../../../data';
import { CheckChatIcon, DeleteIcon, DoubleCheckChatIcon, OptionsVerticalIcon, PinIcon, SendIcon, VoiceRecorderIcon } from '../../../assets/icons/icons';
import {
    Menu,
    PaperProvider,
} from 'react-native-paper';
import { formatTimestamp } from '../../../utils/utils';
import ScreenLayout from '../../../components/screen-layout/ScreenLayout';


const iconStatusMessage = (status) => {
    const icons = {
        SEEN: <DoubleCheckChatIcon color="#35E3AF" size={14} />,
        SENT: <CheckChatIcon color="#7B7B7B" size={14} />,
        DELIVERED: <DoubleCheckChatIcon color="#7B7B7B" size={14} />,
    }
    return icons[status]
}

export default function Chat() {
    const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
    console.log(id);

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const openMenu = () => setVisible(true);
    const closeMenu = () => setVisible(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const flRef = useRef();

    const messages = dataChats[id]?.messages || [];


    return (
        <ScreenLayout withHeader>
            <PaperProvider>
                <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        headerTitle: "Message",
                        headerTintColor: "black",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                        },
                        headerShadowVisible: false,
                        headerBackTitle: '',
                    }}
                />
                <View className="rounded-lg bg-green-p-50 p-4">
                    <View className="flex-row justify-between">
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-4">
                            <Image source={{ uri: images[0].src }} style={{ width: 52, height: 52, borderRadius: 15, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />
                            <Text className="font-semibold text-lg">John Doe</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-4">
                            <Text className="font-normal text-xs">12/09/2024</Text>
                            <View>
                                <Menu
                                    contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white", position: 'relative', top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0, width: 120 }}
                                    visible={visible}
                                    onDismiss={closeMenu}
                                    anchor={<TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu}>
                                        <OptionsVerticalIcon size={16} />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>}>
                                    <Menu.Item onPress={() => { }} title="Pin" leadingIcon={() => <PinIcon size={22} />} />
                                    <Menu.Item onPress={() => { }} title="Delete" leadingIcon={() => <DeleteIcon />} />
                                </Menu>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <Text className="font-semibold text-sm mt-3">About the publish: <Text className="font-normal text-sm">Publish little</Text></Text>
                </View>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}
                    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 90 : 0}
                >
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <FlatList
                            ref={flRef}
                            data={messages}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.content}-${index}`}
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <View className={`flex-row w-full ${item.me ? "justify-end" : ""}`}>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text className="text-gray-500 text-xs text-right">{formatTimestamp(item.timestamp)}</Text>
                                        <View className="flex-row items-center">
                                            <View
                                                className={`py-2 px-3 rounded-lg ${item.me ? "bg-green-primary" : "bg-white"}`}
                                            >
                                                {item.reaction && (
                                                    <View className="bg-white rounded-full w-6 h-6 items-center justify-center absolute z-50" style={styles.reaction}>
                                                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{item.reaction}</Text>
                                                    </View>
                                                )}
                                                <Text className="text-black text-lg">{item.content}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-1 justify-end mt-1">
                                            <Text className="text-gray-500 text-xs text-right capitalize">{item?.status}</Text>
                                            {iconStatusMessage(item?.status)}
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )}
                            contentContainerStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
                        />
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-2 mb-6 mt-2">
                            <TextInput
                                className={"text-black bg-white rounded-md px-5 py-3 flex-1"}
                                placeholder="Escribe un mensaje..."
                                placeholderTextColor="#9E9E9E"
                                keyboardAppearance="dark"
                                onChangeText={setText}
                                value={text}
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { }}>
                                <View className="bg-green-p-50 rounded-md p-2 w-10 h-10 items-center justify-center border border-green-primary" >
                                    {text.length > 0 ? <SendIcon size={20} /> : <VoiceRecorderIcon size={20} />}
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </PaperProvider>
        </ScreenLayout>
    )
}

If I comment out the Stack.Screen everything works perfectly, but if it is maintained I have display errors that will be seen more clearly in a video that I will leave later.
Every time I type in the input it starts to jump and disappear.
I leave a video where it is shown more clearly.
Sample video
